# Error in hook menu

Tags: hooks, 7

I have used drupal 7.38.I have created a custom hook_menu function().
My code is:

```
function jasmine_custom_menu(){
$items = array();
$items['review'] = array(
    'title' => 'Review Page',
    'page callback' => 'review_page',
    'access arguments' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);  
return $items;
}
function review_page(){
  return 'hello workld';
}
```

after module enable error display like this:
**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in menu_unserialize() (line 400 of D:\xampp\htdocs\jasmine\includes\menu.inc)**

Answer (score 4):

Your `access arguments` need to be an array.  But I believe you are wanting to grant access to this page to everyone, so `access arguments` isn't the right key anyway; you want `access callback`.  Try this:

```
$items['review'] = array(
    'title' => 'Review Page',
    'page callback' => 'review_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```